# There exist vim plugins class manager?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, taglist

I have some newbie question. There is exist vim plugin like  some 'class manager' or 'class perspective" like in eclipse or netbeans or geany ? I mean a perspective where i see a class structures, all methods and functions. I looking this plugins for java, that it will be very usefull for me. I looking for this in google, i found something for C++, but not for java. I will be gratefull for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Vim is not an IDE so you won't find *exactly* what you are after. Anyway, try [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) or [TagList](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use a tagbar with ctags, that's really helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a couple of plugins can show the structure of the current file in a
sidebar; they require the *Exuberant Ctags* tool (`ctags`) to extract the class information from the source file.

- [taglist.vim - Source code browser (supports C/C++, java, perl, python ...](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=273)
- [Tagbar - Display tags of the current file ordered by scope](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465)
- [JavaBrowser - Shows java file class, package in a tree as in IDEs](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=588)